# Entangled particles in a Mach-Zehnder Interferometer

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, interferometry

I am trying to understand the Mach-Zehnder Interferometer (MZI) in case of entanglement. Given a standard MZI with two beam splitters at each end and both paths of equal length. In case we send one photon at a time all photons end up at detector 1 (due to constructive interference) and none at detector 2 due to destructive interference. Thus we can say that each particle displays a wave behavior (due to interference shown as discusses above) [image: MZI]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQMMz.png)

The first beam splitter in above setup is a H/V beam splitter. The particle takes path SB when its horizontally polarized and path RB when vertically polarized.

Now we create 2 entangled photons in the state $1/\sqrt(2)(|HV>+|VH>)$ where H and V represents the horizontal and vertical polarization and send first through MZI and keep second with ourselves. Since the particles are entangled the polarization of this second particle can tell us about the first particle's polarization and thus the 'which way' information after the first particle arrives at any of the detector.

**Query 1:** How does the first particle arrive due to the existence of the entangled particle? Does it start behaving like a particle (and shows no interference) and arrive at Det 1 and Det 2 with 50/50 probability (which is my guess)?

**Query 2:** What happens in the case if we erase the polarization information from the second particle before we send the first through MZI?

Comment: $\langle HV\vert VH\rangle $ is not a state: it’s an inner product and thus a complex number, which under usual conventions would be $0$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Due apologies. What I meant was an entangled state: $1/sqrt(2) (|HV> + |VH>)$. extremely late at night and not a physics student so :). Any comments?

Comment: If the first beam splitter is a polarizing beam splitter that separates H and V then you won't get interference at the second beamsplitter. Then the probability to detect the photon at one of the two detectors is 50-50.

Comment: @flippiefanus Thank you. Since there are two queries I assume this answer is for the first? If possible can you also explain the second?

Comment: can someone please explain why the question was closed? I think it was clear enough. Don't know what else to add or clarify?

Answer (score -1):

The missing physical interactions are the quantum Rayleigh spontaneous and stimulated emissions. "Entangled" photons are destroyed in a dielectric medium. See the following article on the MDPI preprints website:
DOI: 10.20944/preprints202202.0073.v3
Type: Article
Title: Polarimetric Quantum-Strong Correlations with Independent Photons on
the Poincaré Sphere

Comment: Sorry but this answer doesn't make any sense to me (I am a layman with a simple query but this is confusing me).